# onCreateOptionsMenu is never called (toolbar inflate)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, layout-inflater

My Fragment class:

```
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    toolbar =  getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menufragmentmain);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); //i also tried putting this function in oncreate function
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "i never enter this function also" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menufragmentmain, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "i never enter this function" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //some switch cases.....
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I've got a stupid error which I cant find unfourtantly.  I've got a simple toolbar for my fragment. In `onViewCreated` I inflate my actionbar menu with my toolbar.
The issue is that the functions `onCreateOptionsMenu` and 'onOptionsItemSelected' are never called. I've got no clue why.

Things i checked in other similar questions with the same issue:

- I checked if my main activity has a `onCreateOptionsMenu` or'onOptionsItemSelected'. It doesn*t
- Checked if my style class has NOT: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`

None of the points unfourtantly work. What did I miss. Do I need to check something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Fragment-owned app bar guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment) which explains how to use a Fragment-owned Toolbar, you **do not** use any of the `setHasOptionsMenu()`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, or `onOptionsItemSelected()` APIs - those are only used for activity owned app bars.

Instead, you would follow the [guide for handling menu click events](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment-click) by using the `Toolbar` APIs:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    toolbar =  getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menufragmentmain);

    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onMenuItemClick called" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //some switch cases.....
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer, is it better to have a fragment-owned appbar or a activity owned appbar (like the answer suggested by homerman)

Comment: The page I linked to specifically goes over that. If your app bar should be available *everywhere* in your activity, having it be owned by the activity makes sense. If it changes from fragment to fragment or is not present on certain screens, it should be part of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the toolbar in the host `Activity`. Then override the menu handling in each `Fragment` wherever necessary.

Here's some generic scaffolding (with comments):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Report that this Fragment has an options menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate then menu, and THEN call super()
    // Note the order of the invocations

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle menu item selections

    final int itemId = item.getItemId();

    switch(itemId) {
      case R.id.my_menu_option_x: ...; return true;
      case R.id.my_menu_option_y: ...; return true;
      case R.id.my_menu_option_z: ...; return true;
      default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
}
```